# How do I loop through CSV file of websites and use curl to test if they're online?

Tags: php, pdo, cron

This cron job php script finds the csv file on my server then loops through the urls on it. It attempts to check if its loaded via https or http or its offline via curl.  This curl request may be taking up too much time. I've done this via post through ajax and it completes the job, but I needed to do this via cron job and a csv file. Are there any other possible solutions?

Can you find a reason why it doesn't complete the task?

Any help would be great.

```
function url_test($url){

  $timeout = 20;
  $ch = curl_init();
  curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER  , true);  // we want headers
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_NOBODY  , true);  // we don't need body
  curl_setopt ( $ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url );
  curl_setopt ( $ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1 );
  curl_setopt ( $ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, $timeout );
  $http_respond = curl_exec($ch);
  $http_respond = trim( strip_tags( $http_respond ) );
  $http_code = curl_getinfo( $ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE );


  if ( ( $http_code == "200" ) || ( $http_code == "301")) {

    return true;
  } else {

    return false;

  }

}
```

// run on each url

```
$offline = 0;
$fullcount = 0;
if (($handle = fopen("/pathtocsv/".$csv, "r")) !== FALSE)
  {
  while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE)
  {
      $num = count($data);
      for ($c = 0; $c < $num; $c++)
        {

         $https = "https://".$data[$c];
         $https = strtolower($https);

         $http = "http://".$data[$c];
         $http = strtolower($http);

         $http = preg_replace('/\s+/', '', $http);
         $https = preg_replace('/\s+/', '', $https);


      $site = $data[$c];


     if(url_test($https)) 
      { 
        $fullcount++;
          echo $https. " <br>";

          ?>

          <?php
      }
      else if(url_test($http))
      {
        $fullcount++;
          echo $http. " <br>";
          ?>

          <?php
      }else{

           echo $site. " <br>";

          $mysqltime = date("Y-m-d H:i:s", $phptime);
          try
            {
            $conn = new PDO("conn info here);

            // set the PDO error mode to exception

            $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
            $sql = $conn->prepare($sql);

            $sql = "INSERT INTO table (url,csv,related)
                VALUES ('$site','$csv',1)";

            // use exec() because no results are returned

            $conn->exec($sql);
            echo "New record created successfully";
            }

          catch(PDOException $e)
            {
            echo "Connection failed: " . $e->getMessage();
            }

          }
         curl_close( $ch );

      }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the get_headers() function. [reference](http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-headers.php)

It will return a response similar to:

```
Array
(
    [0] => HTTP/1.1 200 OK
    [1] => Date: Sat, 29 May 2004 12:28:13 GMT
    [2] => Server: Apache/1.3.27 (Unix)  (Red-Hat/Linux)
    [3] => Last-Modified: Wed, 08 Jan 2003 23:11:55 GMT
    [4] => ETag: "3f80f-1b6-3e1cb03b"
    [5] => Accept-Ranges: bytes
    [6] => Content-Length: 438
    [7] => Connection: close
    [8] => Content-Type: text/html
)
```

which you can use to validate as needed.

As for why the task you're running does not complete. Have you checked the error logs.

Comment: thanks I did use the get_headers like this,                                                                 
                $curl = curl_init();
                    curl_setopt_array( $curl, array(
                        CURLOPT_HEADER => true,
                        CURLOPT_NOBODY => true,
                        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
                        CURLOPT_URL => 'https://'.$site ) );
                    $headers = explode( "\n", curl_exec( $curl ) );
                    curl_close( $curl );
but it still doesn't complete the list with the cron job.